# Extract the valid portions of a mostly JSON file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm using `jq` to parse this file:

```
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
{
  name: '',
  success: false,
  error: '',
  data: {
    video: ''
  }
}
```

And obviously running `jq < foo.json` yields:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10
```

Because it can't parse

```
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
```

Is there way using Bash or `jq` itself to extract the remaining portion which is valid JSON?

```json
{
  name: '',
  success: false,
  error: '',
  data: {
    video: ''
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON. JSON strings are enclosed in **double** quotes, not single ones.

Comment: If you just want to strip everything before the `{`, that's an easy awk one-liner. That said, whatever's writing your human-readable success and error count to stdout instead of stderr (which is where informational and diagnostic logs belong) should be fixed.

Comment: That said, I'm tempted to close this as "unclear what you're asking". The question claims you want to extract valid JSON from a file that contains other content, but then you show _invalid_ JSON. Is that a typo made when asking the question? Is your real data format something other than JSON? We don't know.

Comment: @ikegami, perhaps, but "parse the valid JSON from the file" reads to me quite unambiguously to contain an assertion that the file _already contains valid JSON_.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Actually, I take it back :) They want to ignore the first two lines and parse the remaining, which they incorrectly claim is valid JSON

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I have fixed the question (without removing the error, of course)

Answer (score 3):

If you add a line with '[' at the beginning and another with ']' at the end, then:

```
hjson -j  input.txt
```

yields:

```
[
  "Successes: 0",
  "Failures: 1",
  {
    "name": "",
    "success": false,
    "error": "",
    "data": {
      "video": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Since this is valid JSON, you can pipe it to jq to extract whichever pieces you want.

An interesting lossless possibility is to recognize key-value pairs:

```
jq 'map(if type == "string" and index(":") 
        then [splits(": *")]
             | {(.[0]): .[1] | (tonumber? // .)}
        else . end)'
```

With your sample, this would produce:

```
[
  {
    "Successes": 0
  },
  {
    "Failures": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "success": false,
    "error": "",
    "data": {
      "video": ""
    }
  }
]
```

#### Caveat

The above assumes that if a top-level item is a string with more than one colon, then it is acceptable to discard the string contents after the second colon.

Comment: This is probably the most _practical_ answer, but still needs a 3rd-party tool and some massaging which could be performed in a very fragile bash and jq-native way instead!

Answer (score 1):

To add another guess, while this is not valid JSON, at least some YAML parsers can handle it, which may be available to the next step in the chain you may be consuming input into and even easier than piping through `jq`

For example [`pyyaml`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) for Python (common 3rd-party [LibYAML](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml)-based parser) can handle this directly

```py
>>> s = """{
...   name: '',
...   success: false,
...   error: '',
...   data: {
...     video: ''
...   }
... }"""
>>> yaml.safe_load(s)  # returns a Python dictionary
{'name': '', 'success': False, 'error': '', 'data': {'video': ''}}
```

I present this rather-gross solution for the 1-liner buffs

```sh
python3 -c "import sys,json,yaml; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(''.join([x for x in sys.stdin][2:]))))"
```

> `imports` libs
> read each line from `stdin`
> slice from the first two `[2:]`
> reconnect 'em with `.join`
> parse as yaml to a dictionary
> stringify dict to json

Complete example (useless use of cat to demonstrate consuming from pipe)

```sh
cat << EOF | python3 -c "import sys,json,yaml; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(''.join([x for x in sys.stdin][2:]))))" | jq
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
{
  name: '',
  success: false,
  error: '',
  data: {
    video: ''
  }
}
EOF
```

```
{
  "name": "",
  "success": false,
  "error": "",
  "data": {
    "video": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check, if the json is valid, you could do something like this:

```
jq < foo.json > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```

If the json in `foo.json` is not valid, `$?` will contain something unequal `0`.
If `$? == 0` -- then the json was valid.

BTW: It's not just because of the `Success` and `Failures` keys (which are outside of the json object) that your json is invalid -- also all the keys and string-values have to be quoted (with double quotes).
So e.g. a valid version would be:

```
{
  "Successes": 0,
  "Failures": 1,
  "name": "",
  "success": false,
  "data": {
    "video": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that checking `$?` explicitly is not particularly good form. `if foo; then ...` is better than `foo; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...`: it lets features like `set -e` and `trap ERR` know that the exit status is used for branching; it's less prone to having `$?` modified by error (f/e, if someone adds an extra logging line), etc.

Answer (score 0):

To emit all but the first two lines of a file, you can use the following:

```sh
( read; read; cat ) <foo.json
```

This will produce

```js
{
  name: '',
  success: false,
  error: '',
  data: {
    video: ''
  }
}
```

But contrary to your claims, this is not valid JSON, and `jq` isn't able to work with that either. If that's your ultimate goal, use `hjson` to massage that JS into JSON as @peak [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943509/589924).

Answer (score 0):

The following is a response to the task described in the title:

> Extract the valid portions of a mostly JSON file

Given a file in which each JSON entity of interest has a type other than "string" and is on a single line, there is a jq solution that will extract them:

```
jq -nR 'inputs | fromjson? | select(type!="string")' input.txt
```

The following variant may also be of interest:

```
jq -nR 'inputs | fromjson?' input.txt
```